# No puedo cerrar terminar bucle en Python (nivel principiante). Es un Tic Tac Toe. El juego no termina aunque haya ganador

Tags: python

resulta que soy nuevo en aprender programación, comencé con Python y quiero hacer como primer proyecto un pequeño Tic Tac Toe, el problema es que al final no puedo terminar el bucle incluso cuando ya hay un ganador, no se como, alguna ayuda?
Al inicio escribo las casillas del tablero, y trato de colocarlas en una variable, luego escribo las condiciones para ganar, es decir que haya 3 iguales en fila, columna o diagonal, y que ninguna casilla equivalga a su valor inicial de "-". Después agrego las funciones de turnos y otra funcion para verificar si ya se ha cumplido una de las condiciones para ganar. El problema es al iniciar el juego, ya que el loop se mantiene incluso aunque ya ganó alguien, y llevo dos horas y media aqui probando varias formas y nomas no puedo. Agradeceria me ayudaran a terminarlo. Gracias!

```
#Juego de Tic Tac Toe

#Tablero
board = ["-","-","-","-","-","-","-","-","-"]
 
#Casillas del 1 al 9
Casilla0=board[0]
Casilla1=board[1]
Casilla2=board[2]
Casilla3=board[3]
Casilla4=board[4]
Casilla5=board[5]
Casilla6=board[6]
Casilla7=board[7]
Casilla8=board[8]

#Condiciones para ganar: De la "a" a la "h" para mantener nombres cortos:
a = ((Casilla0 == Casilla1) and (Casilla1 == Casilla2) and (Casilla0 !="-"))
b = ((Casilla3 == Casilla4) and (Casilla4 == Casilla5) and (Casilla3 !="-"))
c = ((Casilla6 == Casilla7) and (Casilla7 == Casilla8) and (Casilla6 !="-"))
d = ((Casilla0 == Casilla3) and (Casilla3 == Casilla6) and (Casilla0 !="-"))
e = ((Casilla1 == Casilla4) and (Casilla4 == Casilla7) and (Casilla1 !="-"))
f = ((Casilla2 == Casilla5) and (Casilla5 == Casilla8) and (Casilla2 !="-"))
g = ((Casilla0 == Casilla4) and (Casilla4 == Casilla8) and (Casilla0 !="-"))
h = ((Casilla2 == Casilla4) and (Casilla4 == Casilla6) and (Casilla2 !="-"))


#Mostrar el tablero
def show_board():
    print (board[0] + "|"+ board[1] + "|" + board[2])
    print (board[3] + "|"+ board[4] + "|" + board[5])
    print (board[6] + "|"+ board[7] + "|" + board[8])

#Iniciar turno jugador "X"
def turno_jugador_1_X():
    x= input ("Turno del jugador 1. Elija una posición del 1 al 9:")
    if board[((int(x))-1)]!= "X" and [((int(x))-1)]!="O":
           board[((int(x))-1)] = "X"
           show_board()
    else:
        print ("Esta posición ya está ocupada! Selecciona otra!")
        show_board()
        turno_jugador_1_X()
        
#Iniciar turno jugador "O"
def turno_jugador_2_O():
    o= input ("Turno del jugador 2. Elija una posición del 1 al 9:")
    if board[((int(o))-1)]!= "X" and [((int(o))-1)]!="O":
           board[((int(o))-1)] = "O"
           show_board()
    else:
        print ("Esta posición ya está ocupada! Selecciona otra!")
        turno_jugador_2_O()

#Verificar si existe un ganador 
def checar_si_hay_ganador():
       if ((a or b) or (c or d) or (e or f) or (g or h)):
        return True
       else:
         return False
         
#Iniciar el bucle del juego
def iniciar_juego():
      
     while True:
         turno_jugador_1_X()
         turno_jugador_2_O() 
         if checar_si_hay_ganador():
           break
           
iniciar_juego()
```

Comment: Quita los asteriscos `*`

Comment: @Christian Creo que los asteriscos es para hacer referencia al problema

Comment: Lo que hace  global es declarar que la variable es global, no asignes la variable con ese keyword, pon `global HayUnGanador` justo al inicio de tu función, debajo de `def iniciar_juego():` y luego en el condicional solo usa `HayUnGanador = True`

Comment: Bueno, entonces el problema es que al declarar como global no se puede  hacer la asignación en la misma línea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me he permitido refactorizar el código y reimplementar el método de cálculo del ganador por claridad. A mi me marea ver esos bloques de instrucciones idénticas donde pequeños errores de tipeo esperan agazapados a producir daño.

#### Determinar si hay un ganador

Un análisis exhaustivo de todos los juegos muestra que sólo hay 8 posiciones a ocupar para ganar: las tres filas, las tres columnas y las dos diagonales. Si todas las piezas en una fila/columna/diagonal son iguales, tenemos un ganador.

Para chequear la igualdad, defino una función a la medida del problema:

```
board = ["-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"]

def todos_iguales(lista):
    return lista[0] != '-' and lista[0] == lista[1] and lista[0] == lista[2]
```

A continuación debo llamar esa función con listas de tres celdas extraídas del tablero. Para las filas es fácil; se aplica rebanada de listas; para el resto construyo la lista a mano.

```
def hay_un_ganador():
    #   Revisar las tres filas
    for indice in range(0, 9, 3):
        if todos_iguales(board[indice:indice + 3]):
            return True
    #   Revisar las tres columnas
    for indice in range(3):
        if todos_iguales([board[indice], board[indice + 3], board[indice + 6]]):
            return True
    #   Revisar las dos diagonales.
    if todos_iguales([board[0], board[4], board[8]]) or todos_iguales([board[2], board[4], board[6]]):
        return True
    return False
```

A la función `show_board` le agregue el número de celda para "orientar" al usuario (se puede mejorar ...):

```
def show_board():
    print("1 " + board[0] + "|" + board[1] + "|" + board[2])
    print("4 " + board[3] + "|" + board[4] + "|" + board[5])
    print("7 " + board[6] + "|" + board[7] + "|" + board[8])
```

#### Turno del jugador

No necesito dos funciones cuasi-idénticas para manejar las jugadas de cada jugador. Puedo usar una función genérica que reciba el número del jugador y el símbolo a ocupar en el tablero. Esta función pide y valida la jugada:

```
def turno_jugador(numero, simbolo):
    while True:
        x = int(input(f"Turno del jugador {numero}. Elija una posición del 1 al 9:")) - 1
        if board[x] == "-":
            board[x] = simbolo
            break
        else:
            print("Esta posición ya está ocupada! Selecciona otra!")
    show_board()
```

#### Ciclo principal

Finalmente, un juego consiste en pedir jugadas alternativamente a cada jugador, revisando tras cada una si hay un ganador. En tal caso, terminar.

```
def iniciar_juego():
    show_board()
    while not hay_un_ganador():
        turno_jugador(1, 'X')
        if not hay_un_ganador():
            turno_jugador(2, '0')

iniciar_juego()
```

**Demo**

```
board = ["-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"]

def todos_iguales(lista):
    return lista[0] != '-' and lista[0] == lista[1] and lista[0] == lista[2]

def hay_un_ganador():
    #   Revisar las tres filas
    for indice in range(0, 9, 3):
        if todos_iguales(board[indice:indice + 3]):
            return True
    #   Revisar las tres columnas
    for indice in range(3):
        if todos_iguales([board[indice], board[indice + 3], board[indice + 6]]):
            return True
    #   Revisar las dos diagonales.
    if todos_iguales([board[0], board[4], board[8]]) or todos_iguales([board[2], board[4], board[6]]):
        return True
    return False

def show_board():
    print("1 " + board[0] + "|" + board[1] + "|" + board[2])
    print("4 " + board[3] + "|" + board[4] + "|" + board[5])
    print("7 " + board[6] + "|" + board[7] + "|" + board[8])


def turno_jugador(numero, simbolo):
    while True:
        x = int(input(f"Turno del jugador {numero}. Elija una posición del 1 al 9:")) - 1
        if board[x] == "-":
            board[x] = simbolo
            break
        else:
            print("Esta posición ya está ocupada! Selecciona otra!")
    show_board()

def iniciar_juego():
    show_board()
    while not hay_un_ganador():
        turno_jugador(1, 'X')
        if not hay_un_ganador():
            turno_jugador(2, '0')

iniciar_juego()
```

produce:

```
1 -|-|-
4 -|-|-
7 -|-|-
Turno del jugador 1. Elija una posición del 1 al 9:1
1 X|-|-
4 -|-|-
7 -|-|-
Turno del jugador 2. Elija una posición del 1 al 9:2
1 X|0|-
4 -|-|-
7 -|-|-
Turno del jugador 1. Elija una posición del 1 al 9:4
1 X|0|-
4 X|-|-
7 -|-|-
Turno del jugador 2. Elija una posición del 1 al 9:5
1 X|0|-
4 X|0|-
7 -|-|-
Turno del jugador 1. Elija una posición del 1 al 9:7
1 X|0|-
4 X|0|-
7 X|-|-

Process finished with exit code 0
```