# bucles y variables python

Tags: python, funciones, bucle-for, bucles

estuve haciendo un juego del 3 en raya con una inteligencia artificial que en principio debería determinar cuando una jugada es ganadora, ese es el actual objetivo en principio, el problema que me surge es que me gana sin ni tan si quiera jugar por algún motivo, creo que el problema esta relacionado contra el bucle for dentro de la función jugada_ordenador, pero no es cual es el problema sinceramente, aquí les dejo el código para que le echen un vistazo.

```
import random


# --------- variables goblales -----------

# esto es la matriz donde trabajaremos, en este caso tan solo es una tupla
Tablero = ["-", "-", "-",
         "-", "-", "-",
         "-", "-", "-"]

TableroImaginario=["-", "-", "-",
                 "-", "-", "-",
                 "-", "-", "-"]

# Esta variable indicara si el juego debe seguir o ha finalizado
el_juego_funciona = True

# Esta variable nos indicara quien es el ganador si lo hay, sino permanecera en estado None
Ganador = None
GanadorImaginario = None
#  Esta variable indica de quien es el turno, de forma predeterminada empezaran las cruces 
jugador_humano="X"
ordenador="O"
Jugador_del_Turno = jugador_humano
# ------------- funciones ---------------

# Jugar al 3 en ralla
def Jugar():

  # reiniciar el tablero
  MostrarTablero()

  # bucle principal, el bucle cerrara cuando haya ganador o tablas
  while el_juego_funciona:

    #Jugada de cada jugador
    #*************
    Jugada(Jugador_del_Turno)

    # comprobamos victoria y empate
    Comprobar_fin_juego()

    # cambiamos de X a O y viceversa
    Cambiar_jugador()
  
  # Cuando el bucle principal termina indicamos quien ha ganado
  if Ganador == "X" or Ganador == "O":
    print(Ganador + " ha ganado. ")
  elif Ganador == None:
    print("Tablas.")


# aqui mostramos el tablero de pantalla, en un lado tendremos nuestro propio tablero y en el otro una indicacion numerica
def MostrarTablero():
  print("\n")
  print(" " +  Tablero[0] + " | " + Tablero [1] + " | " + Tablero[2]    +"            1|2|3")
  print("------------" +                                                 "          -----")
  print(" " +  Tablero[3] + " | " + Tablero [4] + " | " + Tablero[5]    +"            4|5|6")
  print("------------" +                                                 "          -----")
  print(" " +  Tablero[6] + " | " + Tablero [7] + " | " + Tablero[8]    +"            7|8|9")
  print("\n")


# funcion usada para las jugadas, ambos jugadores comparten funcion
def Jugada(Jugador):

    if Jugador=="X":
        jugada_humana()
    elif Jugador=="O":
        jugada_ordenador()


def jugada_ordenador():
    #tramemos las variables globales.
    global GanadorImaginario
    contador=0
    print("es turno del ordenador ")
    for i in range(1,9):
        TableroImaginario=Tablero
        posicionImaginaria= i
        posicionImaginaria=int(posicionImaginaria)
        posicionImaginaria-=1
        if TableroImaginario[posicionImaginaria]== "-":
            TableroImaginario[posicionImaginaria]="O"
            comprobar_victoria_imaginaria()
            if GanadorImaginario== "O":
                Tablero[posicionImaginaria]="O"
                contador=1
                break
            else:
                pass

        else:
            pass
    if contador==0:
        valido=False
        while not valido:
            posicion= random.randint(1,9)
            posicion= int(posicion) -1
             # Nos aseguramos que se coloca en una casilla no escogida previamente
            if Tablero[posicion] == "-":
             valido = True
            else:
             print("El ordenador esta pensando ")
    return


def jugada_humana():
    # pedimos una jugada
  print("es el turno del Jugador ")
  posicion = input("elige una casilla entre 1-9: ")

  # valido sera un valor para generar un bucle que solo se abrira cuando se de una jugada valida
  valido = False
  while not valido:

    # Nos aseguramos de que juegan dentro del tablero
    while posicion not in ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]:
      posicion = input("Input invalido. elige una casilla entre 1-9: ")
 
    # corregimos la posicion para que el ordenador la entienda
    posicion = int(posicion) - 1

    # Nos aseguramos que se coloca en una casilla no escogida previamente
    if Tablero[posicion] == "-":
      valido = True
    else:
      print("casilla ocupada, piensa otra opcion. ")

  # colocamos la pieza en nuestra "matriz"
  Tablero[posicion] = "X"

  # refrescamos el tablero con la nueva jugada
  MostrarTablero()

# funcion para comprobar el final de juego
def Comprobar_fin_juego():
  comprobar_victoria()
  comprobar_tablas()


# funcion para comrpobar si hay una victoria
def comprobar_victoria():
  # Set global variables
  global Ganador
  # traemos las variables globales necesarias
  ganador_fila = comprobar_filas()
  ganador_columna = comprobar_columnas()
  ganador_diagonal = comprobar_diagonales()
  # Obtenemos el jugador victorioso
  if ganador_fila:
    Ganador = ganador_fila
  elif ganador_columna:
    Ganador = ganador_columna
  elif ganador_diagonal:
    Ganador = ganador_diagonal
  else:
    Ganador = None


# comprobacion de cada fila
def comprobar_filas():
  # traemos las variables globales necesarias
  global el_juego_funciona
  # comprobamos que todos los valores en una fila sean iguales y no esten vacios
  fila_1 =Tablero[0] ==Tablero[1] ==Tablero[2] != "-"
  fila_2 =Tablero[3] ==Tablero[4] ==Tablero[5] != "-"
  fila_3 =Tablero[6] ==Tablero[7] ==Tablero[8] != "-"
  # si hay linea hay victoria
  if fila_1 or fila_2 or fila_3:
    el_juego_funciona = False
  # obtenemos el ganador
  if fila_1:
    return Tablero[0] 
  elif fila_2:
    return Tablero[3] 
  elif fila_3:
    return Tablero[6] 
  # seguimos el codigo si no hay fila
  else:
    return None


# comprobamos las columnas para ganar
def comprobar_columnas():
  # traemos las variables globales necesarias
  global el_juego_funciona
  # comprobamos que tienen el mismo valor y no estan vacias
  columna_1 =Tablero[0] ==Tablero[3] ==Tablero[6] != "-"
  columna_2 =Tablero[1] ==Tablero[4] ==Tablero[7] != "-"
  columna_3 =Tablero[2] ==Tablero[5] ==Tablero[8] != "-"
  # si hay columna hay victoria
  if columna_1 or columna_2 or columna_3:
    el_juego_funciona = False
  #  obtenemos el ganador
  if columna_1:
     return Tablero[0] 
  elif columna_2:
    return Tablero[1] 
  elif columna_3:
    return Tablero[2] 
  # seguimos el codigo si no hay columna
  else:
    return None


# comprobamos las diagonales para ganar
def comprobar_diagonales():
  # traemos las variables globales necesarias
  global el_juego_funciona
  # comprobamos que tengan el mismo valor y no sea vacio
  diagonal_1 =Tablero[0] ==Tablero[4] ==Tablero[8] != "-"
  diagonal_2 =Tablero[2] ==Tablero[4] ==Tablero[6] != "-"
  # si hay diagonal hay victoria
  if diagonal_1 or diagonal_2:
    el_juego_funciona = False
  # obtenemos el ganador
  if diagonal_1:
    return Tablero[0] 
  elif diagonal_2:
    return Tablero[2]
  #continuamos el codigo
  else:
    return None


# funcion para comprobar si hay tablas
def comprobar_tablas():
  # traemos las variables globales necesarias
  global el_juego_funciona
  # si el tablero esta lleno hay tablas
  if "-" not in Tablero:
    el_juego_funciona = False
    return True
  # De otra forma no hay tablas
  else:
    return False


def comprobar_victoria_imaginaria():
    Ganador_fila_imaginaria = comprobar_filas_imaginarias()
    Ganador_columna_imaginaria = comprobar_columnas_imaginarias()
    Ganador_diagonal_imaginaria = comprobar_diagonales_imaginarias()

    if Ganador_fila_imaginaria:
      GanadorImaginario = Ganador_fila_imaginaria
    elif Ganador_columna_imaginaria:
     GanadorImaginario = Ganador_columna_imaginaria
    elif Ganador_diagonal_imaginaria:
      GanadorImaginario = Ganador_diagonal_imaginaria
    else:
      GanadorImaginario = None



def comprobar_filas_imaginarias():
 # comprobamos que todos los valores en una fila sean iguales y no esten vacios
  fila_1imaginaria =TableroImaginario[0] ==TableroImaginario[1] ==TableroImaginario[2] != "-"
  fila_2imaginaria =TableroImaginario[3] ==TableroImaginario[4] ==TableroImaginario[5] != "-"
  fila_3imaginaria =TableroImaginario[6] ==TableroImaginario[7] ==TableroImaginario[8] != "-"
  # obtenemos el ganador
  if fila_1imaginaria:
    return TableroImaginario[0] 
  elif fila_2imaginaria:
    return TableroImaginario[3] 
  elif fila_3imaginaria:
    return TableroImaginario[6] 
  # seguimos el codigo si no hay fila
  else:
    return None

def comprobar_columnas_imaginarias():
    # comprobamos que tienen el mismo valor y no estan vacias
  columna_1imaginaria =TableroImaginario[0] ==TableroImaginario[3] ==TableroImaginario[6] != "-"
  columna_2imaginaria =TableroImaginario[1] ==TableroImaginario[4] ==TableroImaginario[7] != "-"
  columna_3imaginaria =TableroImaginario[2] ==TableroImaginario[5] ==TableroImaginario[8] != "-"

  #  obtenemos el ganador
  if columna_1imaginaria:
     return TableroImaginario[0] 
  elif columna_2imaginaria:
    return TableroImaginario[1] 
  elif columna_3imaginaria:
    return TableroImaginario[2] 
  # seguimos el codigo si no hay columna
  else:
    return None

def comprobar_diagonales_imaginarias():
    # comprobamos que tengan el mismo valor y no sea vacio
  diagonal_1imaginaria =TableroImaginario[0] ==TableroImaginario[4] ==TableroImaginario[8] != "-"
  diagonal_2imaginaria =TableroImaginario[2] ==TableroImaginario[4] ==TableroImaginario[6] != "-"

  # obtenemos el ganador
  if diagonal_1imaginaria:
    return TableroImaginario[0] 
  elif diagonal_2imaginaria:
    return TableroImaginario[2]
  #continuamos el codigo
  else:
    return None

#  funcion para cambiar jugador en cada turno
def Cambiar_jugador():
  # traemos las variables globales necesarias
  global Jugador_del_Turno
  #si el jugador es X pasamos a O
  if Jugador_del_Turno == jugador_humano:
    Jugador_del_Turno = ordenador
  #  si el jugador es O pasamos a X
  elif Jugador_del_Turno == ordenador:
    Jugador_del_Turno = jugador_humano

Jugar()

input("pulsa enter para terminar el juego")
```

en principio entiendo que la lógica de juego esta bien ya que hice una versión para dos jugadores con las mismas bases, y la parte seleccionar números aleatorios por parte de la "IA" debería funcionar correctamente también ya que tengo otra versión en la que tan solo juega de dicha forma, espero que esos detalles les sirvan de ayuda.

aqui muestro lo que se muestra en el terminal cuando juega el ordenador [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cual es la pregunta concreto? Pareciera que quieres que alguien lo termina por ti,

Comment: Nonono, no queria dar esa impresion perdona, tan solo no estoy entendiendo porque finaliza la partida ya que en ningun momento puse nada de finalizar la partida en la función del pensamiento de la IA, y estoy seguro de que el error fue una tonteria pero llevo un tiempo buscandolo y no encuentro nada, mi duda es porque salen esos resultados por la terminal

Comment: Hay necesidad de poner todo el código?? Lo que no funciona es solo una parte, no todo. Solo pon la parte en donde crees que está el problema y si te piden más detalles vas añadiendo más código

Comment: si, seria mejor, gracias por la idea, ahora mismo lo modifico

Comment: Tu función que c9.0ruena la victoria imaginaria debería de retornar un valor 6a que luego haces la comprobación

Comment: No entiendo lo que intentas decirme

Comment: Lo siento, decía que tu función que comprueba la victoria imaginatia debe de retornar algún valor, pues luego lo usas para hacer otra validación

Comment: si, lo se, pero para el jugador me pareció mas estetico usar numeros de 1-9 por eso mas tarde modifico el valor restandole uno, aunque sea para el ordenador decidi hacerlo asi para que se pareciese lo maximo posible al protocolo que uso para la jugada del jugador, igualmente ahora lo modificare asi a ver si me soluciona algo, lo del bucle del juego ahora lo añado entero a la pregunta no te preocupes.

Comment: que clase de valor deberia retornarme? un boolean o algo asi? no tengo muy claro como hacerlo

Comment: `return GanadorImaginario` y al hacer el llamado a esta función debes de almacenar el valor

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [No puedo cerrar terminar bucle en Python (nivel principiante). Es un Tic Tac Toe. El juego no termina aunque haya ganador](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/464801/no-puedo-cerrar-terminar-bucle-en-python-nivel-principiante-es-un-tic-tac-toe)

Comment: sigue dandome error aun retornando GanadorImaginario, subire una captura de lo que pasa por si ayuda

Comment: lamento decir que no Candid Moe, mi problema no esta en el juego en si, sino en el momento de jugar el ordenador

Comment: Revisa bien y prueba por separado la función `jugada_ordenador()` hay cosas que no me cuadran, pero yo ni he creado esa función y no se bien lo que haces